# Vectors and motion in a plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

> A particle travels with speed $50 m/s$ from the point $(3,-7)$ in the
>   direction $7i-24j$ . Find its positional vector after 3 seconds.

**My approach**:
It has travelled a distance of 150m in the direction given by the unit vector $\frac{7\hat i - 24 \hat j}{25} $
.

So, its position is now $210\hat i -720 \hat j$. But it started from $(3, - 7)$, so I have to subtract that to get $197\hat i - 713\hat j$. But I think this answer is awkward, and I may have gone wrong. So, please tell me if I am right, and if yes, can you suggest any shorter way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displacement :$$\vec r_f-\vec r_i = \vec d =|d| \hat d $$

$\vec r_i$=  position vector initial. ie. $3\hat i -7 \hat j$  ;  $|d|=150m$ as found , and $\hat d$ is the direction .

Comment: $ \hat d$ is just the unit vector I mentioned, right?

Comment: @SaurabhRaje: yes that's it.

Comment: ie$\frac{7 \hat i - 24 \hat j}{25}$

Comment: @SaurabhRaje: There is no need to post new comments every thing you mention for.If this persist that can lead to suspension , I have seen 1 case.

Comment: @user007, I appreciate your concern, but please tell me what should be done if I need to clarify a point?

Comment: @SaurabhRaje: It's not like that . But as you sometimes do , write a new comment for every equation it's wrong. Like ""ie.`eq`"" must have been a part of 1st comment itself. Don't take tension though `:P`.